# BlocListener with SetState vs Multiple BlocBuilder

Tags: flutter, bloc, state-management

This is a performance-related question, both codes work and reliable.

Is there any efficiency related difference between the following structures? (in terms of Widget Tree refreshes and rebuilds)

If there's any better way, please address it.

1. Using only BlocListener with SetState()

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocListener(
      bloc: locator<SomeCubit>(),
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state is DataLoaded) {
          setState(() => data = state.data);
        }
      },
      child: Column(
        children: [

          // Widget #1
          data.length <= 0
              ? Text('No Data')
              : Container(),
          
          // Widget #2
          if (data.length > 0 && data.length <= 2)
            Text('Not enough records'),
          
          // Widget #3
          Column(
            children: data.map((e) => SomeTile(e)).toList(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

VS
2. Using multi BlocBuilder, something like this:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [

        // Widget #1
        BlocBuilder(
          builder: (context, state) {
            if (state is DateLoaded) {
              return state.data.length <= 0 ? Text('No Data') : Container();
            }
            return Container();
          },
        ),

        // Widget #2
        BlocBuilder(
          builder: (context, state) {
            if (state is DateLoaded) {
              if (data.length > 0 && data.length <= 2) {
                return Text('Not enough records');
              }
            }
            return Container();
          },
        ),

        // Widget #3
        BlocBuilder(
          builder: (context, state) {
            if (state is DateLoaded) {
              return Column(
                children: state.data.map((e) => SomeTile(e)).toList(),
              );
            }
            return Container();
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: P.S: Please ignore any logic or data related issues in code, this is only for demonstrating the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Bloc builder also uses setstate underneath so performance in these two cases will be similar. Bloc builder shines where you need to rebuild a certain part of widget tree, where setstate will trigger build method again rebuilding all its ancestor widgets properly placed bloc builder will build only necessary widgets.